# How do I keep a <div> that's underneath a partially transparent .png, scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay, scrollable

I have a div that contains scrollable content and I want to place an overlay on top of that div.

However, the overlay makes everything underneath it unscrollable and unclickable (obviously). Is there a way around that? Some HTML/CSS/JS combination maybe that keeps  visible and yet allows  the div that is right underneath it to still be scrollable/clickable ?

The reason I'm asking is because I have a div with a background-image (that's my overlay). But the image has a hole in the middle (it's a partially transparent png). So the div that is actually underneath this overlay is visible. So I want to be able to interact with that div.

I know I can write Js to transfer any click/scroll events from one element to another but I have lots of instances of the above setup on a single  page, so writing that Js for every single case would be an overkill.

Thank you in advance for your help.

CSS

```
#scroller {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}
#scroller>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50px;
}
#scroller-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="scroller">
<div></div>
</div>
<div id="scroller-overlay"></div>
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/7L8cmeuo/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with CSS in the scroller overlay:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

All clicks and other mouse events in the area of the transparent PNG will then fall through to the elements below it. See updated version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/em37fuqf/).

Comment: woah, this is cool. i've learned something today. and the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events) is quite good.

Comment: Awesome! I never knew that existed!